# Create a multilingual chatbot

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, chatbot

I created a chatbot using PyTorch an I want to make it support the French language. Note that I want to train the chatbot so that it can respond to technical questions.

One of the things that came to my mind is to use translation APIs but since the chatbot is expected to respond to technical questions translation APIs might provide inaccurate information

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I make the chatbot respond to questions in other languages(in this case French)?

Comment: Train it in other languages (in this case French).

Comment: How? right now I have an intents.json file that contains patterns and their corresponding responses in English. Am I supposed to add French patterns on the same file or what else?

Comment: If you know how to create a chatbot for the English language, trained on English training data, then one obvious approach would be to do the same thing to create a chatbot for the French language using French training data. Is your question how to get the French training data? Yes, translating the English training data seems like an obvious choice, which should work well as long as the translation program is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Most LLMs don't particularly care which language you ask the question in. It will respond in the language in which you ask the question. You can also add it to the prompt instructions by setting the system message (or adding to it).

"You are a helpful IT assistant and will respond in French at all times". Something like that. You can try it out.

Note that this is for the LLM input and output, you will still need to take care of the French UI of your bot.

Comment: I am not talking about the UI I am talking about how can I implement this(technically speaking). Right Now I have trained the chatbot to respond only to questions in English and want to make it respond to French ones also. I am not using any LLM just relying on predefined patterns

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using predefined patterns, you'll probably get way better performance implementing a language model for your chatbot.

You can simply use models that are pre-trained on french? I know XLM-Roberta is trained on hundred languages so it will support your task, as the tokenizer will tokenize the sentence and the model will understand its french based on the input_ids.